# ¿Qué puerta de enlace debo instalar?

Tags: powerbi, gateway

Tengo un equipo con un usuario sin permisos de administrador. Quiero instalar una puerta de enlace para que, con la cuenta Power Bi Pro de ese usuario, pueda conectar a mis orígenes de datos: excel, csv, Access, Sharepoint, Onedrive, etc. La instalación la hará un usuario con permisos admin.

Mi duda es ¿qué puerta de enlace debo instalar?. Más tarde añadiré algún usuario más a esos orígenes. ¿Debo instalar la puerta de enlace personal o la estándar?

Gracias.

Comment: Instala la puerta de enlace estándar si el origen de datos sera colaborativo, la personal solo si el origen de datos sera utilizado por ti, lee mas en [Gateway BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/es-mx/gateway/).

Comment: Gracias. El origen de datos será colaborativo.